# Is it possible to read JMSDeliveryMode property in .NET WMQ API?

Tags: .net, jms, ibm-mq

I'm trying to consume JMS messages send over WebSphere MQ (WebSphere MQ Server v7) by .NET application using .NET WMQ API. I'm using WebSphere MQ Client v7.5 and amqmdnet.dll version 7.5.0.0.

There is some very strange behavior when reading `JMSDeliveryMode` property (`Dlv` property from `jms` RFH2 folder). The property value send by JMS application (servlet hosted in WebSphere Application Server v7) is set to `Persistent` (2) but my .NET client always reads 1 (which means `Non_persistent`). I need to read the correct value because my .NET application works as router/forwarder and it must forward message with correct configuration.

I tried to simulate JMS messages using [RFHUtils](https://sites.google.com/site/ibmmiddleware/rfhutils). When I set delivery mode to 1 and send it to my .NET client it again reads 1 but if I also change persistence of MQ message in MQMD it reads 0. It looks like the value in `JMSDeliveryMode` is not used at all and .NET client always reads value from `Persistence` property but it is incorrect behavior! These two properties have different ranges of correct values:

`JMSDeliveryMode` correct values (from jms.jar):

- 1 - `DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT`
- 2 - `DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT`

`Persistence` correct values (from amqmdnet.dll):

- 0 - `MQC.MQPER_NOT_PERSISTENT`
- 1 - `MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT`
- 2 - `MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENCE_AS_Q_DEF` / `MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENCE_AS_TOPIC_DEF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is again bug in IBM's amqmdnet.dll. After disassembling the library with [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) and checking the code responsible for reading JMS properties (`GetJmsProperty` private method of `MQMessage` class) I found this:

```
if (name.Equals("JMSDeliveryMode"))
{
   // Properties never contain the property with such name!
   if (this.properties.ContainsKey("JMSDeliveryMode"))
   {
      ...
   }
   return this.Persistence;  // Executes always
}
```

The problem is that `properties` collection never contains any property with `JMSDeliveryMode` as a key. `properties` collection contains RFH2 headers in format *RFH2Folder.RFH2PropertyName*. The correct property name for `JMSDeliveryMode` is `jms.Dlv`! Interestingly `GetJmsHeader` method reads all JMS properties and all other properties use correct RFH2 name when searching in properties collection!

The situation was even worse when I checked the reverse operation - private method `SetJmsProperty` from `MQMessage` class. Setting `JMSDeliveryMode` contains this code:

```
else if (name.Equals("JMSDeliveryMode"))
{
    if (value is int)
    {
        int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        switch (num2)
        {
            // Non persistent JMS message creates persistent MQ message  
            case 1:
                this.Persistence = 1;
                break;
            // Invalid value for JMS delivery mode            
            case 0:
                this.Persistence = 0;
                break;
            // Great if I try to create persistent JMS message I will 
            // get MQRC_PERSISTENCE_ERROR exception!            
            default:
                base.throwNewMQException(2, 0x7ff);
                break;
        }

        queue.Enqueue(num2);
        // Correct RFH2 identifier is used
        this.properties.Add("jms.Dlv", queue);
    }
    else
    {
        base.throwNewMQException(2, 0x9a9);
    }
}
```

So setting `JMSDelivery` mode will either fire exception or set invalid persistence! Here is small test for reproducing the problem:

```
[Test]
public void PutAndGetMessageWithDeliveryMode() {
    using (MQQueue queue = _queueManager.AccessQueue(TestQueue, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF)) {

        MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
        message.SetInt4Property("JMSDeliveryMode", 2);
        message.WriteString("some string");
        message.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;

        queue.Put(message); 

        MQMessage readMessage = new MQMessage();
        queue.Get(readMessage); 

        Assert.AreEqual(2, readMessage.GetInt4Property("JMSDeliveryMode"));

        queue.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Values for Persistence in MQ .NET is correct and you can compare with `cmqc.h` header file  as both amqmdnet and C MQI are both MQ native APIs.

```
0 - MQC.MQPER_NOT_PERSISTENT
1 - MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT
2 - MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENCE_AS_Q_DEF / MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENCE_AS_TOPIC_DEF
```

The jms.jar DeliveryMode enumeration has defined a different value. I would imagine MQ JMS implementation would internally handle this appropriately and set correct MQ specific values in MQMD and RFH2 properties.

Regarding your test using RFH2Util. Values set in MQMD tab and JMS could be different. You can set DeliveryMode to 1 in JMS tab and Persistent Msg to `No` in MQMD tab. When a message is put, MQMD.Persistence will show up as `0` and JMSDeliveryMode will show up as 1. I confirmed this values by viewing message in MQ Explorer. The MQ .NET API is just giving you what it got from the message. As far as I know RFHUtil is a tool to set RFH properties. It simply sets/gets RFH properties. It does not have the intelligence of a MQ JMS implementation.

In my opinion "JMSxxxx" properties are best handled by a JMS implementation and not by a native implementation like MQ .NET.

Comment: MQ .NET API doesn't give me what I get in the message. It even doesn't allow me sending the correct value. If MQ.NET API is  "native" implementation it should give me a full control. I don't understand why upper level layer (JMS) has behavior hardcoded directly in the transport layer (MQ). This should be defined separately in some bridge.